# Must I consider the implications of Azure before developing for it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, cloud

My intention is to develop and MVC app driven by WCF services.

I will then like to deploy these to Azure.

Can I go about developing my app and services without any consideration to the fact they will be hosted in Azure earlier on in the lifecycle? Or must I structure it differently?

EDIT: More specifically - am I right in saying I can develop this application just as I would prior to deciding it would be hosted in Auzre?

Comment: please stick to the nature of questions that this community is about. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: I will update my OP to be more specific. If that's not what you're eluding to, then you will have to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advert that appears on this page as I answer this question says *"Move apps to the cloud without rewriting them"*.

- The official position from Microsoft (who pays for the ads), is that you can migrate to Azure late in the development cycle.
- The reality is:

  - You lose a lot of the benefits of could computing if you don't architect specifically for the cloud. This applies to any cloud platform, not just Azure.
  - There are likely some hidden 'gotchas' that will trip you up if you develop for normal Windows and then try and move it up to Azure. Just this morning I had a developer that was frustrated by errors on SQL Azure that didn't occur on his dev machine. The approach to SQL Azure is different to standard SQL (feature differences, throttling, etc).

There are two 'it depends' that are related:

1. Are you intending to use cloud services or Azure websites? Azure websites are easier to migrate because they are closer to a traditional web development approach.
2. Applications with lots of moving parts, or that are subject to high load, need special consideration (regardless of the target platform), so you will want to optimise for, and take advantage of, Azure specifics.

If you have a good reason **not** to develop specifically for Azure (such as your employers official position, platform portability, etc) then don't worry about Azure for now. If your long-term intention is to run your app on Windows Azure, then code for Azure up front — the effort to take it off Azure (lock-in) will form part of your decision later on.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my research and understanding, it is a better practice to consider your future implementation to azure prior to any development, however even if you later decide to move an existing application to azure, you may need to perform some modifications to your code.

please bear in mind that, Microsoft is currently offering websites in azure that can host you asp application, you may want to read more about that.

here is some links that may help you.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/web-sites/
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/